# Unable to click element on page Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to move to page 2 and beyond of this page (pagination) with python selenium and spent a few hours on this.  I am getting this error, and would be thankful of any help..Error from chromedriver

```
is not clickable at point(). Other element would receive the click
```

My code so far:

```
class Chezacash:
    t1 = time.time()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)


    def controller(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.chezacash.com/#/home/")
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.panel-heading")))    
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'),"html.parser")
        self.parser(soup)
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='paginate_button active']/following-sibling::li").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'),"html.parser")
        self.parser(soup)


    def parser(self, soup):
        for i in soup.find("table", {"id":"DataTables_Table_1"}).tbody.contents:
            date =  i.findAll("td")[0].get_text().strip()
            time =  i.findAll("td")[1].get_text().strip()
            home =   i.findAll("td")[4].div.span.get_text().strip().encode("utf-8")
            home_odds =  i.findAll("td")[4].div.findAll("span")[1].get_text().strip()
            draw_odds =  i.findAll("td")[5].div.findAll("span")[1].get_text().strip()
            away =   i.findAll("td")[6].div.span.get_text().strip().encode("utf-8")
            away_odds =  i.findAll("td")[6].div.findAll("span")[1].get_text().strip()
            print home

cheza = Chezacash()
try:
    cheza.controller()
except:
    cheza.driver.service.process.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM) # kill the specific phantomjs child proc                            # quit the node proc
    cheza.driver.quit()
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: A quick comment on your code. In the `for i` loop, the first line should store `i.findAll("td")` in a variable and then `date` and so on would access the different `[0]`, etc. elements. Your current code is rescraping the page (`.findAll()`) for each assigned variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if instead you would locate the "Next" button *by link text*, scroll into it's view and then click:

```
next_button = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next")
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next_button)
next_button.click()
```

I would also maximize the browser window before navigating to the page:

```
self.driver.maximize_window()
self.driver.get("https://www.chezacash.com/#/home/")
```